# When does $2^{n}$ divide $3^{n}-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The title says it all. For what natural numbers $n$ does $2^n$ divide $3^n - 1$? By substituting values I can see that this happens for $n = 1, 2, 4$ but are there more? I am not able to prove/disprove.

Comment: is this a question from a book or are you asking by yourself?

Answer (score 7):

If $n$ is odd then $3^n-1 \equiv 2\pmod 4$. Otherwise the number of factors of $2$ dividing $3^n-1$ is exactly $2+\upsilon_2(n)$by litfing the exponent, which is at most $2+\ln_2(n)$. Hence we need
$$n \le 2+\ln_2(n) \implies n<5.$$
Therefore the unique solutions are $1,2,4$.

Comment: You should know there is a separate LTE version for $p=2$ :) The above result holds for $n$ even. Wait, I search you a reference

Comment: See the last theorem before problems http://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h324597 ; anyway, if $n$ is even you could say that $3^n-1= 9^{n/2}-1$ and $4\mid 9-1$ ;)

Comment: I would add the reason why $n<5$. $n\le 2+\ln_2(n)\Leftrightarrow \ln_2(2^n)\le \ln_2(4n)\Leftrightarrow 2^n\le 4n\Leftrightarrow 2^{n-2}\le n$, from which induction gives $n<5$ (since if we assume $2^k>k+2, k\ge 3$, then $2^{k+1}=2^k 2>(k+2)2>k+3$).

Comment: Here's the fact jodran used in the answer (a version of LTE (Lifting the exponent lemma)): ($a,b$ odd, $n$ even) $\Rightarrow v_2(a^n-b^n)=v_2(a+b)+v_2(a-b)+v_2(n)-1$, where $v_2(k)$ denotes the largest $m$ such that $2^m\mid k$.